# Best Way For Join Parent ID

Tags: sql, mysql

I have a table named "categories" like this:

```
id              int(11)      NO  PRI  NULL  auto_increment
name            varchar(50)  NO       NULL   
seo_name        varchar(50)  NO  MUL  NULL   
parent_id       int(11)      NO       NULL   
total_projects  int(11)      NO       NULL   
order           int(11)      NO  MUL  NULL
```

`id` and `parent_id` are columns related. `parent_id` refers rows relationships. For example I am querying like this

```
SELECT * FROM categories WHERE id = 99
```

But I want to get parent's category id (it is stored in `parent_id`) in same query. How can i do this? Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this.

```
SELECT t1.* , t2.name as parent_category 
  from categories t1 
  INNER JOIN categories t2 on t1.id = t2.parent_id
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM Categories cat
INNER JOIN Categories parent
on cat.parent_id = parent.id
```

Is this what you mean?